# Macro for Desing mode

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a button in the excel workbook, and associate a macro to it that does the following, when I click on it, activate the design mode (The design mode is the button that is located in: Programmer - Controls - Design mode) and then when you click the other button disable design mode. What I intend is that the person does not have to go to the option (Programmer - Controls - Design mode), but from a button in the Excel workbook when clicking it enables me the design mode, and in case of not having enabled the scheduler option, enable it.

Comment: Thuis question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058915/turn-on-and-turn-off-design-mode-vba

Comment: As you wish....